# Unable to pass data to other viewController ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a little problem, because I can't pass data to another view controller.

```
-(void)barcodeData:(NSString *)barcode type:(int)type
{
    mainTabBarController.selectedViewController=self;

    [status setString:@""];

    [status appendFormat:@"Type: %d\n",type];
    [status appendFormat:@"Type text: %@\n",[dtdev barcodeType2Text:type]];
    [status appendFormat:@"Barcode: %@",barcode];
    [displayText setText:status];
    codede1String = barcode;
     NSLog(@"%@",codede1String);


    [self updateBattery];
}
```

In the code above I put a barcode in the String `codeString1`. So far no problem, but when I send this data to the other viewController barCodeString suddenly is NULL.

I pass data to viewcontroller like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  if  ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"barcode"]) {
        main =[ segue destinationViewController];
      main.code1.text = codede1String;


    }  

}
```

So how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to understand your code with the help of a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in the viewDidLoad of the view controller, then it works fine

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 codedeString=[[NSString alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that code1 is a text field, text view or label. If so, the reason this doesn't work, is that the outlets for main are not yet set at the time of prepareForSegue. You need to create a string property in main and set its value to code1String in prepareForSegue. Then, in main's viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear, set code1's text value to that string.

Answer (score 0):

Note that IBOutlets of the destination view controller are not set yet in `prepareForSegue`. So if `main.code1` represents a `UILabel`, it will be nil because the view is not yet loaded. You should pass the string directly using a setter method: `[main setCodeString:codede1String]` and then configure the user interface in `viewDidLoad`: `self.code1.text = [self codeString]`.

Comment: code1.text is a textfield
I have tried this   [main setBarcodeString:codede1String]; and in the other view controller in viewDidLoad i did this self.code1.text = [self barcodeString]; But problem is the sane

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, it helped me once for the same kinda issue (but with xibs)

Add one more line, just before any assignments

```
[main.view setAlpha:1.0f];
main.code1.text = codede1String;
```

Hope this will help you as well.